# Laravel | storage:link

Tags: laravel, file, storage

I have a problem to use storage:link.

I use this  code

```
$PDFPath = $request->ficheiro->store('public/documentacao_interna');
```

But i try open and show this link 404(Not found):

http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public%2Fdocumentacao_interna%2FY5zUoVc8SMwWRraz0aApa4Bm5SpQZxHYi06kao5n.pdf

but if I remove the "public", it already shows the attachment.

What am I doing wrong in the link? In recording or showing?

Thanks.

EDIT:

My view have this :

```
<td><a href="{{url('storage',$doc->ficheiro)}}" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the File is stored, then to display use Localhost URL like:

```
http://localhost/storage/public%2Fdocumentacao_interna%2FY5zUoVc8SMwWRraz0aApa4Bm5SpQZxHYi06kao5n.pdf
```

Comment: this link can only work by removing "public" from the address